# Merge NSManagedObject with the "same" NSManagedObject in another NSManagedContext (Multi Threaded)

Tags: multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have two entities that are in a 1:n relationship. In this question I will use **company** and **employes**. In my application you can create a new **company** and automatically find their **employees**.

I create many threads which all have their own `NSManagedObjectContext`. In these threads I create one new employe. I can create new **employees** (within a thread) and then merge the two contexts using  `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:`.

The problem is that I don't know where to create the new **company**. If I create it in the threads and add the new **employe**, I get one company for each **employe**.

If I create a **company** before creating the **employes** (in their own threads), the **company** is in the wrong `NSManagedObjectContext`. And I it is impossible to move the **company** object from the main `NSManagedObjectContext` to the one in the thread.
I found a way to copy the company to the thread's `NSManagedObjectContext`, but when merging the contexts I have one **company** with one **employe**, one with two, one with three and so on.

You may say I could create all the **employees** and after creating them, add them to one new company. But I don't want this, because I have bound the entities to a `NSArrayController` in order to present them in two TableViews. And I want to update the tableview as soon as a new employe has been created.

I also want to be able to update a **company** and look for new **employees**. At least at this point, I need a already existing **company** in order to refresh it. So I have to somehow get it and change it without changing it from two threads at the same time...

This problem makes me crazy. Sitting on it for two days now. Is there someone who can help me?

**Edit:** When using `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:`, is it possible to somehow say that it's always the same company?

**Edit2:** Here's the Test App I talk about in the comments:  http://www.file-upload.net/download-3674327/CoreDataMultiThreading.zip.html

Thanks a lot!

*(please excuse my pronunciation)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have almost exactly the same problem and I think it might be one of the biggest problems that exists in the CoreData architecture :(

Threads don't play well with core data. I usually end up with one core data 'writer' thread and all the other threads would only read from the persistent store (updating themselves as the writer thread does it's updates). (Actually, I use an NSOperationQueue and NSOperation subclasses to deal with threading for me but it's basically the same - as long as only one thread is writing at any one time I'm OK)

There's two solutions to your problem.

You could create the company first and save it to the persistent store before triggering any threading at all. Then, all your threads that are making employees can just retrieve the same company in their respective NSManagedObjectContexts. To make sure that all the threads have the *same* company in their NSManagedObjectContexts, pass the company's NSManagedObjectID to each thread and retrieve it from the local NSManagedContext using `objectWithID:`. (One of the rules of using CoreData in multiple threads is to never pass managed objects around, always pass the ID and get a new copy per thread)

The other solution is to do all of your core data write operations that might have a collision act sequentially (my favoured solution) - this would ensure that the first operation makes the company and the other operations would just use the already existing one.

Hope that helps!

---

EDIT Moving object between threads example

This method will create a company and give you the managed object id

```
// Create the company and save it. 
- (NSManagedObjectID *)createCompanyOnThreadOne {
     NSManagedObject *company = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Company" inManagedObjectContext:context];
     [company setName:@"My Company"];
     [[company managedObjectContext] save:nil];
     return [company objectID];
}
```

// Then, for each background thread that you want to add an employee on, pass in the object ID :

```
// Create the company
ManagedObjectID *companyID = [self createCompanyOnThreadOne];

// Create three employees
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(createEmployee:) withObject:companyID];
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(createEmployee:) withObject:companyID];
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(createEmployee:) withObject:companyID];
```

// And the method that run in the background would look something like

```
- (void)createEmployee:(NSManagedObjectID *)companyID {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = ... get a new context for this thread here ... 

    // Get the company from the persistent store
    NSManagedObject *company = [context objectWithID:companyID];

    // Make your employee and save it
    NSManagedObject *employee = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [employee setCompany:company];

    // Save it
    [context save:nil];
}
```

However, I don't recommend this many threads writing at the same time - it's going to get messy - what happens if two threads add an employee to a company at the same time - I bet one thread will save OK and the second thread will tell you there is a merge conflict? I guess you'll find out.

Comment: Thx for your answer! The first solution seems to be the best for my application. But now I have trouble getting the Company from one context to the other. I tried [threadContext insertObject:[mainContext objectWithID:[currentCompany objectID]]]; Then (of course) it tells me: 'An NSManagedObject may only be in (or observed by) a single NSManagedObjectContext.' So I tried to copy the Company using a method I found here: http://pastebin.com/efkji4sy. But then again I have one company for one employee... Hmmm :(

Comment: Hi, I've added a quick example - I typed it from memory so there might be typos. The important thing is that I'm passing the objectID between the threads, not the company object itself.

Comment: Thx for the update. But it won't work. NSManagedObject *company = [context objectWithID:companyID]; will lead in the same error I described before: "An NSManagedObject may only be in (or observed by) a single NSManagedObjectContext."Also they are still in different contexts, so [employee setCompany:company]; will lead in "Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'company' between objects in different contexts"

Comment: Why would calling `objectWithID:` lead to that error - you're not passing a managed object between contexts, just it's ID! Can you edit your question and add the code that's causing the error so I can see more of what's going on?

Comment: Okay, I now implemented your suggestion. I get the error: "Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'company' between objects in different contexts (source = <Employe: 0x104c2fb50> (entity: Employe; id: 0x104c30360 <x-coredata:///Employe/t0637908F-BD79-4827-85DF-C39D12CF257F5> ; data: { ... " and it sets a breakpoint to the line [employee setCompany:company];

Comment: Company is still in the main context. so it gives me that error.

Comment: Then you're using the wrong `company` (or the wrong `context`) - in my example the company object you are using to add the employee to is loaded from the same context that created the employee object - they are both local variables in my `createEmployee:` method and aren't shared with any other methods.

Comment: (I've just re-read my example and edited it to make it more obvious that's what I'm doing!)

Comment: There is still something I do wrong. I put your example in a Test-Application and uploaded it (see edited Question). Can you please have a look at it? It somehow seems to work, but doesn't add all Employees. o_O Thx a lot so far!

Comment: You could also use the parent child pattern and create children for your users and bind them to a company (that you create in the parentcontext) in the parent context and finally save the parent. Also I recommend using the WriterContext as a parent of this whole operation. https://www.raywenderlich.com/174082/multiple-managed-object-contexts-with-core-data-tutorial